# Sidestep the default username and email when validate it with ajax unique Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can i sidestep current username and password of the user when updating his information? For example - when i try to update only the name it shows me that email is already taken and vice versa. That way i can not update only the or only the email, only both of them.
My actionUpdate:

```
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $model = new UpdateForm();
        $id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $user = $this->findModel($id);

        //default values
        $model->username = $user->username;
        $model->email = $user->email;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['UpdateForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['UpdateForm'];

            if($model->validate())
            {

                $user->username = $model->username;
                $user->email = $model->email;
                $user->password = md5($model->password);

                $user->update();

                $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $user->id]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My UpdateForm rules:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'password', 'username'], 'required'],
            [['email', 'password', 'username'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['username', 'password', 'email'], 'trim'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            [[ 'email', 'username'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use  both for unique

eg:

```
// a1 and a2 need to be unique together, and they both will receive error message
[['a1', 'a2'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
```

in your case

```
[[ 'email', 'username'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'username']],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html

Comment: It was hard for me to understand that rule when i read it for first it, maybe because of the language barrier, but now i get it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok! it was helpful but now seem i can not update only the password without changing one of both username or email. It is my bad because i did not notice that i have 3 fields username,email,password. What should be the way to do that? Thank you again and i am sorry but i am still learning and it is kind of confusing sometimes :)

Comment: what do you mean with  "i have 3 fields "  ?? you mean 3 unique ?? .. explian better of post a new well described specific question  .. (don't change this otherwise became incomprehensible..)

Comment: Ok! Will ask in new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the fields one at a time. You need to remove the required fields. He then checks that 3 must exist. Delete this line:

```
[['email', 'password', 'username'], 'required'],
```